# Handling URL Binding Failures in IIS Express

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, wcf

I have deployed my **WCF** webservice locally and its working fine, But in a method I got unexpected result so I decided to **debug** my webservice in **Visual Studio**. But I get the following errors. (Even I am running VS with **administrative privileges**).
I also exposed endpoints in `web.config` but still not working here is the error from Log file,

> Failed to register URL "http://localhost:61241/" for site
>   "TaxiRiderService" application "/". Error description: Access is
>   denied. (0x80070005)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced same problem windows7, VS15, 
I tried adding/removing localhost:port# to urlacl using netsh command but din`t work.

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:63746/ user=everyone`

I had to disable Internet Connection Sharing ICS for my ethernet (I had enabled this for sharing internet to VM) and I was able to debug/run solution locally.
[image]

Answer (score 19):

Open .**CSPROJ** from project,  Delete the whole lines for
  <DevelopmentServerPort> and <IISUrl> ...

http://gizmoblogr.com/821/workaround-url-binding-failure-error-iisexpress

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure, that your're debugging the service with an elevated account?
This error is quite common if you're trying to host a service on a non-default port using a standard user.

You could try to register that port to that specific user. Open an elevated command prompt and execute the follwing command:

```
add urlacl url=http://localhost:61241/TaxiRiderService user=YOURDOMAIN\youruser
```

For details have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try `net stop hns` and then `net start hns` to restart Hosted Network Service. This helped me resolving this issue running Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

on cmd with admin access

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:80/ user=everyone
```

From Microsoft Docs: [Handling URL Binding Failures in IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express)

Answer (score 0):

The problem came for me after messing with Hyper V Virtual Switch manager.
I had the lan card driver uninstalled and reinstalled again.
Problem solved at once.

Answer (score -1):

Running visual studio as an administrator solves this issue for me.
Sometimes .vs folder also needs to be deleted.