# Unable to run IIS Express after Updating Visual Studio 2019 - 16.0.1

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2019

I switched from the visual studio from 2015 to 2019, everything works fine but after their first update I got the mentioned error.

[image: error]

Comment: Check out some recommendations on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling, I found the solution [here](https://realmpkdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/cannot-start-the-website-because-administrative-privileges-are-required-to-bind-to-the-hostname-or-port/) just follow the steps

Comment: please add some essential parts in your answer in case the URL goes down

Comment: this is not a solution but a workaround :(